# POWER8 architecture 'flat' virtual address space

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, virtual-address-space

As mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_POWER#The_architecture), can anyone explain what is meant by a 'flat' 32 bit space?

Text for the lazy:

> Another interesting feature of the architecture is a virtual address
>   system which maps all addresses into a 52-bit space. In this way
>   applications can share memory in a "flat" 32-bit space, and all of the
>   programs can have different blocks of 32 bits each.

Comment: Have you read the Power ISA documentation from http://www.power.org/? I'm sure the answer to your question is in there somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "flat" address space means that the virtualized 32-bit space used for each program is independently and directly accessible in consecutive offsets starting at byte 0 all the way through xFFFFFFFF.

Contrast this with what are typically termed "segmented" address spaces where an address is composed of a segment number or descriptor, and then a smaller number of bits as an offset into that segment/descriptor.

The memory management system performs the sleight of hand to translate a 32-bit address reference into a specific location within the actual 52-bit address space provided by the underlying architecture.

Comment: I think this is basically correct.  A *flat* address space is one without holes.  As opposed to *segmented*, I would think *unmapped* might be the contrast.  Since this is for the Power8, I would say that each process could have 4GB worth of swap for itself for about 1 million processes.